# Question about convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When $\frac 12\lt m\lt 1$, consider two sequences $a_k=(2\pi k+\frac 1k)^{\frac 1m}$ and $b_k=(2\pi k)^{\frac 1m}$, then $\lim_{k\to \infty}\vert a_k-b_k \vert =0$. But I don't know how this claim proves.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The pictures seems to have little to do with uniform continuity? Also, please typeset in mathjax. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a beginner this program. But I change all words, please help my analysis problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that 
$$a_{k}-b_k = \frac{\big(1+\frac{1}{2\pi k^2}\big)^{1/m}-1}{\big(\frac{1}{2\pi k}\big)^{1/m}}$$
and then apply L'Hospital as $k\to\infty$.